# if two functions attain maximum at common point, will the sum of the two functions also attain maximum at the common point?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, maxima-minima

Let $X$ be a compact hausdorff space and $E$ be a Banach space. 
Suppose that $f,g:X \rightarrow E$ are continuous Banach-space valued functions. 
Denote the sup-norm on $E$ as $\| f \| = \sup_{x \in X}\| f(x) \|.$

> Question: If $\|f\|=\|f(x_0)\|$ and $\|g\| = \|g(x_0)\|$ for some $x_0
>  \in X,$ is it true that $\|(f+g)\| = \|(f+g)(x_0)\|?$ In other words,
>   if two functions attain maximum at common point, will the sum of the
>   two functions also attain maximum at the common point?

This seems quite intuitive from a graph. But I do now know a proof of it.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $g(x_0) = -f(x_0)$  e.g.?

Comment: "intuitive from a graph" perhaps if you graph positive valued functions, making the question about $|f|+|g|$ rather than $|f+g|$